# how to print text file in 2d array in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print 2D Array from .txt file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830453/how-to-print-2d-array-from-txt-file-in-java)

8.00 28.00
18.00 28.00 
8.00 23.00
12.00 20.00 
15.00 30.00 
12.00 32.00 
12.00 20.00 
18.00 31.00 
29.00 25.00 
6.00 28.00
7.00 28.00
6.00 24.00
14.00 30.00 
11.00 23.00 
12.00 20.00 
31.00 24.00 
11.00 20.00 
17.00 23.00 
14.00 32.00 
15.00 23.00 
8.00 20.00
17.00 31.00 
7.00 20.00
12.00 23.00 
15.00 20.00 
12.00 20.00 
21.00 20.00 
27.00 27.00 
18.00 20.00 
25.00 27.00 
46.00 13.00
26.00 10.00 
47.00 22.00 
44.00 14.00
34.00 4.00
34.00 4.00
44.00 7.00
39.00 5.00
20.00 0.00
43.00 11.00 
43.00 25.00 
34.00 2.00
25.00 10.00 
50.00 9.00
25.00 9.00
39.00 2.00
34.00 7.00
44.00 15.00 
36.00 3.00
40.00 5.00
49.00 21.00 
42.00 7.00
35.00 1.00
30.00 2.00
31.00 13.00 
53.00 12.00 
40.00 4.00
26.00 4.00
50.00 55.00
57.00 51.00 
62.00 52.00 
56.00 52.00 
59.00 40.00 
61.00 68.00 
66.00 49.00 
57.00 49.00
62.00 58.00 
47.00 58.00 
53.00 40.00 
60.00 54.00 
55.00 48.00 
56.00 65.00 
67.00 56.00 
55.00 43.00 
52.00 49.00 
67.00 62.00
68.00 61.00 
65.00 58.00 
46.00 53.00 
46.00 49.00 
47.00 40.00 
64.00 22.00 
64.00 54.00 
63.00 64.00 
63.00 56.00 
64.00 44.00 
63.00 40.00

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class csvimport5 {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    double [][] data = new double [87][2];  
    File file = new File("buydata.txt");
    int row = 87;
    int col = 2;
    BufferedReader bufRdr  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line ;


    //read each line of text file
    while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null && row < data.length)
    {   

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line," ");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens())
    {

        //get next token and store it in the array
        data[col][row] = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
        col++;

    }
    col=0;

    }

    row++;

     for( row = 0; row<data.length; row++){
   for( col = 0; col<data.length; col++){         

    System.out.print(" "+data[86][1]);
   }
   System.out.println();
     }






  }

}
```

It gives output like 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
please help me to print that file in array form

Comment: possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831001/to-print-the-text-file-in-2d-matrix-of-same-dimension-given-in-file-using-java

Comment: possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830786/i-want-to-print-text-file-into-2d-array-of-same-dimensions-given-in-text-file

Comment: @Andreas_D It seems all are from same school :)

Answer (score 2):

You always print `System.out.print(" "+data[86][1]);` and you initialize row to 87 before reading.

You also do `double [][] data = new double [87][2];` which seems to be [row][col] but then you set values using [col][row]. Fix the order to be consistent please. Don't you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s on that line: 

`data[col][row] = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());` ? (Edit: I just saw your other question, so you indeed get the AIOOBE ;) )

This while loop will never run: `while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null && row < data.length)`. You initialize row to 87 which is equal to data.length and thus the statement `row < data.length` is always false.

Edit: I'm stopping here now. I'd suggest you throw your program at a debugger and see what your code really does.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to use a debugger! [Here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) is a good start!