# Input of a 2D array via button and .txt file Processing Java

Tags: java, user-interface, processing

After a thorough survey of this and many other Internet communities I failed to solve my problem. It is about ControlP5 button and my aim of importing 2D array  from previously formated text file with two columns and 19 rows and space separated values. Now my code works but the 2D arrray I designated to hold the values from the txt does not get all of the values but just the last pair in its first row. I know that for loops over all values but stores them only in the first row. I dont know how to push it in another row for reading. This is my code:

```
if(theEvent.isController())
{
    if(theEvent.controller().name() == "mean shape males")
    {
        String loadPath1 = selectInput();
        reader = createReader(loadPath1); //new BufferedReader
        int x=0; //rows
        int y=0; //columns
        String smaLine;
        try
        {
            while ((smaLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] values = smaLine.split(", ");
                for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
                {
                    float[] testC = float(split(values[i], " "));
                    for (int j = 0; j < testC.length; j++)
                    {
                        mat1[j][i] = testC[j];   //THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC MATRIX  
                    }
                }
                x = x+1;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mat1max = maxRet(mat1);
        mat1min = minRet(mat1);
        inputMat = new Grid(2,19,10,130,22,mat1,mat1min,mat1max);
    }
}
```

I used all the advice I could find on Stack Overflow mainly from this post [How to print 2D Array from .txt file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830453/how-to-print-2d-array-from-txt-file-in-java) but I just can`t seem to move the reader onto rows other then the first.

Comment: You'll want to a) sprinkle your code with `println(...)` calls to inspect the state of your variables and to help you find out where the bug is, either that or use a debugger, and b) improve your code formatting as it is *very* hard to read being all left-justified. Luck.

Comment: For each line of input you reset the elements of `mat1[j][i]`, writing over the data you have read previously. Is this intentional?

Comment: @JoniSalonen: Nice catch that I missed. You should change your comment to an answer, I think, because that's probably the problem and solution.

Comment: @Joni Salonen, I think it's an empty 2D array for container. But unless he init it correct, it's probably be mat1[1][1];

Comment: I initialized this matrix like     float[][] mat1 = new float[2][19]; which is the same dimensionality as in the .txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that instead of resetting the elements in `mat1` you want to create a new matrix for each line and store them in a list of some kind. This is how you might do it:

```
List<?> matrices = new ArrayList<?>();
while ((smaLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    float[][] mat = new float[MATRIX_ROWS][MATRIX_COLUMNS];
    String[] values = smaLine.split(", ");
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        float[] testC = float(split(values[i], " "));
        for (int j = 0; j < testC.length; j++)
        {
            mat[j][i] = testC[j];
        }
    }
    matrices.add(mat);
    x = x+1;
}
```

Where is `x` used, by the way?

Comment: X is just a leftover and is not used anywhere I just overlooked it. Still ArrayList does not do the required thing because i need float[][] type array

Comment: Just one float[][]? but each line of your input should produce one float[][] if I've understood correctly. How do you combine them into one?

Answer (score 0):

Swap your `mat1[j][i] = testC[j]` to `mat1[i][j] = testC[j]`

Comment: I tried this but it onbly prints two vertical columns i.e. there are values in the mat1[1][1] and mat1[2][1] instead of mat1[1][1] and mat1[1][2].